# Is this geometry question about a pentagon correct?

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

> In pentagon $ABCDE$, $AB=BC=2,CD=\sqrt{2}$,and $EA= \sqrt{3}$. If $\angle{A}=90^{\circ}$, and $\angle{B} = 120^{\circ}$, what is the area of $ABCDE$?

I just need some reaffirmation that there is no solution to this problem. There are infinitely many pentagons with the properties in the question (try drawing it).

Comment: That may be, but it's possible that nevertheless they all have the same area. (I have no idea whether or not that is true though.)

Comment: They actually can't all have the same area. Try drawing it out and you will see that we can vary $ED$ while keeping $CD = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: All you need to prove what you want is to explicitly find two examples with different areas. This will settle the question with certainty.

Comment: Something must be wrong.  Nothing is said about angle E or side ED or angle C.  D can be any point $\sqrt(3)$ away from C.  Infinite pentagons, infinite area.

Comment: Is this a verbatim record of the question? No possibility of representing the maximum possible area of the pentagon? If not, and it is indeed verbatim, I think you're right.

Comment: @fleablood That's exactly what i'm thinking. If it helps any of you determine where the error occurred or incorrect reasoning, here are the answer choices: (A) 2+2√3 (B) 3+5√3 (C) 6 (D) 2+3√2 (E) 3+2√5

Comment: I think there is a typo in the problem.  If angle C or DE or angle E were given we'd have a solution.  (Although knowing DE would give us two possibilities).

Comment: @BrianTung If the question were asking for the maximum area would it match up with the answer choices?

Comment: No, it would not.

Comment: If it's multiple choice then maybe 4 are impossible (too small) but I'm *way* too lazy to figure that out.

Comment: Where do you think they got those answer choices from, and it seems even more strange to me as this question was proofread by a few people. Could they have actually solved the question wrong and gotten one of those answers? It seems unlikely.

Comment: None are too small, but I think B and E are too big.

Comment: I just asked the problem creator and he disagrees. He says "There is in fact one such pentagon."

Comment: If I'm not mistake b is exactly twice the area of ABCE.  Which, if typo, seems too much of a coincidence.

Comment: Is this a profession puzzle, published and proof-read or is this one of your classmates 'cause...

Comment: Yeah it was one of my classmates problems. He apparently said he made a typo and that it should say concave pentagon. Does that change things?

Comment: I was going to ask.  Concave means that we add (not subtract) the area of the triangle.  Ask him if he forget to mention what DE is equal to.  If we knew that, we'd have it.

Comment: He actually just messaged me back and said "Everything is fixed without the knowledge of the length of $DE$. Try it!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes 7 parameters to define the shape and size of a pentagon. 
The problem gives 6.  So you should have a continuous family of pentagons meeting the conditions.  Hypothetically they could all have the same area but the discussion in comments points in the opposite direction.

The shape, and hence the area, of EABC are determined by the data.

Comment: I agree with zyx. You need information about the value of angle $C$. That way, you define how long $DE$ is, and you can break the pentagon into simpler shapes.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the area of the quadralateral ABCE.  D must be a point of a circle centered at C and of length $\sqrt 2$.  We can set up an equation for that.  So the area is area of quad ADCE $\pm$ area of triangle CDE.  That gives us a range of values.  Maybe 4/5 of the multiple choices are out of range.

Or maybe it was a typo.

====

If CE is the base of CDE then height has a max/min of $\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2$.

I'm too lazy to calculate CD or area ABCE.

====

Actually the area ABCE is easy.  Angle CBX for some point on the perpendicular to AB at B is 30 so if we set X to form a 30-60-90 triangle, we see BX would be $\sqrt 3$ which is the same as AE so ABXE is a rectangle with area $\sqrt 3 2$.  ECX are colinear and area of BCX is $\sqrt 3/2$ so $ABCE$ has area $\sqrt 3* 5/2$.  Triangle CDE has area $3*h/2$ where h $\in [-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]$.

So ABCDE has area $(\sqrt 3 *5 + 3*h)/2$ where $-\sqrt 2 \le h \le \sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think only answers (B) and (E) are out of range. But it was a good thought.

Comment: The area of $ABCE$ is $5\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: $CD$ is given as $\sqrt{2}$, but $CE = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

For constructing a unique pentagon $ABCDE$, it needs either $\angle C$ or the side $ED$ to be known as an additional information. So there could be many pentagons constructed with the given information